# Firebase Functions saying something undefined when it is not

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Getting the following error from firebase functions. I do not understand how registrationList is undefined.

> Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore value. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "registrationList.`0`"). If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

```
 let curRegister = 0;
                // Take inventory down
                if (typeof eventInfo.currentRegister !== "undefined") {
                  curRegister = parseInt(eventInfo.currentRegister) + 1;
                  console.log("KBKBKBBK: " + curRegister);
                } else {
                  curRegister = 1;
                }
                let regList = [];
                // Add the user to the event registration table
                if (typeof eventInfo.registrationList !== "undefined") {
                  regList = eventInfo.registrationList;
                  regList.push(purchaser.id);
                } else {
                  regList = [purchaser.id];
                }
                //update event doc
                admin
                  .firestore()
                  .collection("events")
                  .doc(eventID)
                  .update({
                    registrationList: regList,
                    currentRegister: curRegister,
                  });
                let eventsAttend = [];
                if (typeof purchaser.eventsAttended !== "undefined") {
                  eventsAttend = purchaser.eventsAttended;
                  eventsAttend.push(eventID);
                } else {
                  eventsAttend = [eventID];
                }
                admin
                  .firestore()
                  .collection("fclUsers")
                  .doc(userDocId)
                  .update({ eventsAttended: eventsAttend });
```

Comment: It is pretty unusual for this error message to be wrong. You might want to `console.log(JSON.stringify(regList))` to validate its contents.

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that the first item inside the array is undefined `regList[0]`, this can happen if your array is empty.

You should be health checking your data before pushing it to Firebase.

- check it's type with `Array.isArray(eventInfo.registrationList)`
- Filter out null and empty items with `regList.filter(Boolean)`
- check it's array length to check it's current content count `regList.length > 0`